# PDF Signature - Embed separatly signed hash problem

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am currently working on a web application (1) which allows sending the hash of a pdf file to another application (2). The application (2) returns a signed hash.
With a console application I managed to correctly sign the file but the problem is that we need to have the hash before the Makesignature.SignDetached (*****) function

code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 string unsignedPdf = "c:\\temp\\spec.pdf"; 
 string signedPdf = "c:\\temp\\specSigned5.pdf";
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[1];
 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("certificate here");
 var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
 chain[0] = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());
  using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
   {
    using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
     {
      PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
      PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
      appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 250, 250, 400), 1, "digigo2");
      appearance.Reason = "Reason";
      appearance.Location = "Location";
      appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
      appearance.Certificate = chain[0];
      IExternalSignature signature = new RemoteSignature();                 
      MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
     }
   }
}
```

```
class RemoteSignature : IExternalSignature
 {
  public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
   {
    IDigest messageDigest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest(GetHashAlgorithm());
    byte[] messageHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(messageDigest, message);
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(messageHash));
    Console.ReadKey();
    // i send the hash to the application B and i get 
    // the signed hash and i save it in c:/temp/signedhash.txt
    string SighHashFile = "c:/temp/signedhash.txt";
    string signature = File.ReadAllText(SighHashFile);
    byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
    return signedBytes;
   }
  public virtual String GetHashAlgorithm()
   {
    return "SHA-256";
   }
  public virtual String GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
   {
    return "RSA";
   }
 }
```

I tried using the MakeSignature.SignDeferred () function but the signature is still wrong

code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 string unsignedPdf = "c:/temp/spec.pdf";
 string tempPdf = "c:/temp/temp.pdf";
 string signedPdf = "c:/temp/Signed.pdf";
 string signatureFieldName = "test";
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[1];
 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("certificate here");
 var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
 chain[0] = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());
 string sByte = GetBytesToSign(unsignedPdf, tempPdf, signatureFieldName, chain[0]);
 Console.WriteLine(sByte);
 Console.ReadLine(); 
 // i send the hash to the application B and i get 
 // the signed hash and i save it in c:/temp/signedhash.txt
 string SighHashFile = "c:/temp/signedhash.txt";
 string signature = File.ReadAllText(SighHashFile);
 EmbedSignature(tempPdf, signedPdf, signatureFieldName, signature);
}
```

```
public static string GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate chain)
{
if (File.Exists(tempPdf))
File.Delete(tempPdf);
   using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
    {
     using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf))
      {
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 400), 1, signatureFieldName);
        appearance.Reason = "Reason";
        appearance.Location = "Location";
        appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        appearance.Certificate = chain;
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(appearance.GetRangeStream(), "SHA256");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
     }
   }
}
```

```
public static void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, string signature)
{
byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
   using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
    {
     using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
      {
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);
        MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
      }
    }
}
```

```
private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
 private readonly byte[] signedBytes;
 public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] signedBytes)
  {
   this.signedBytes = signedBytes;
  }

 public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
  {
  }

 public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
  {   
   return signedBytes;
  }
}
```

[Invalid signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Gd9.png)

Comment: Your code is very hard to read. So many empty lines tearing it apart and then no proper indention. If you want people to really read your code and try and help you, you should edit your question and make your code readable.

Comment: That being said... *"the problem is that we need to have the hash before the Makesignature.SignDetached (*****) function"* - **(A)** Which one? Your code has multiple occurrences of `MakeSignature.SignDetached`, both active and in comments. **(B)** Why? Your code looks like trying to prepare the PDF for signing both in (1) and (2), You simply have to decide where you want to do the PDF processing and then do it only there.

Comment: the code (A) works perfectly and we have a signed and verified file.
But our need is to develop a web interface where a user can select several files and sign them at the same time.
the signature api accepts several hashes as input but it redirects to an authentication page.
That's why I tried to work with the temporary file code (B) but I have a problem with cryptographic verification.